# How to hide the menu at the bottom in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

Is it possible to hide the menu at the bottom in TeXstudio?

[image]

I can't find a way to do this...

Comment: Just to know: why do you want it?

Comment: @Sigur: It just bothers me a bit when I'm working. I never use it, so I find it rather redundant.

Comment: Well, I recommend you to learn how to use bookmarks (those 3 flags). Also, the bar allows you to change the dictionary quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar question was asked at http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/60e7239d/#1674

There the answer was, that this is currently (2012) not possible.

---

But if the frustration about this waste of screen space is big enough there is always a workaround. For my personal use, I simply forked a copy of the source code and inserted `status->setMaximumHeight(0);` into `texstudio.cpp`. This does not remove the status bar, but with a height of 0 pixel I can happily ignore it :)

---

**Edit:**

As of version `2.11.2`, the status bar now can be turned of: `View->Show->Statusbar`

[image]